# Here maps display blue globe using latest SDK in android studio ,maps not appearing

Tags: android, here-api

I run the sample application provided by Maps, but it just displays a blue globe. The maps are not appearing, and I don't know what mistake I made. I referred to Maps documentation and GitHub.

Here is my code:

```
package com.here.android.example.routing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.Image;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapMarker;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.customization.CustomizableScheme;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.customization.CustomizableVariables;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.customization.ZoomRange;
import com.here.android.mpa.odml.MapLoader;
import com.here.odnp.util.Log;

import java.util.List;



public class BasicMapActivity extends Activity {

    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;
    MapView mapView = null;


    // map fragment embedded in this activity
//    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.ext_mapview);
        MapEngine.getInstance().init(this, engineInitHandler);
    }

    private OnEngineInitListener engineInitHandler = new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
            if (error == Error.NONE) {
                map = new Map();


                // more map settings
                map.setProjectionMode(Map.Projection.GLOBE);  // globe projection
                map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible(true);
                map.setLandmarksVisible(false);
                mapView.setMap(map);

               // MapLoader.getInstance().addListener(mapLoaderHandler);

                // update packages and get installation state
                MapLoader.getInstance().getMapPackages();
                // more map initial settings

            } else {
                Log.e("get", "ERROR: Cannot initialize MapEngine " + error);

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MapEngine.getInstance().onResume();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onPause();
        }
        MapEngine.getInstance().onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies file

```
 dependencies {
        compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')

        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    }
```

manifest file

```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.here.android.example.routing">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".BasicMapActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
            android:value="" />

        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="HereMapService"
            android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What SDK target are you using?

Comment: Here Map SDK (https://developer.here.com)

Comment: Which revision, 3.3.x? or 3.2.x?

Comment: SDK Version: 3.3.1.237 ,please refer to my output screenshot[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcZ3S8vwiVbQVhuQ1l1WVcwXzQ/view)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting map center with

```
public void setCenter (GeoCoordinate point, Animation animation)
```

or

```
public void setCenter (GeoCoordinate point, Animation animation, double level, float orientation, float tilt)
```

and you can create GeoCoordinate with

```
GeoCoordinate (double latitude, double longitude)
```

Comment: i tried with setCenter (GeoCoordinate point, Animation animation) its not working

Comment: try not using `map.setProjectionMode(Map.Projection.GLOBE);` and again set map center

Comment: hi @abdull thanks for ur reply,i tried this code also      map.setProjectionMode(Map.Projection.MERCATOR); map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(10.786534, 78.86751),Map.Animation.LINEAR),please refer to my screenshots in this link [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcZ3S8vwiVbQVhuQ1l1WVcwXzQ/view) still showing blue globe its not rendering map

Comment: @karthick ok use setZoomLevel with a double parameter

Comment: Am getting this error @ abdull NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "version.hybrid.api.here.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: Something wrong with your connection or host can not be reachable

Comment: hi @abdull, please check my source code [github link](https://github.com/ashk1246/github)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line MapLoader.getInstance().getMapPackages(). This puts the engine in map data download state. And your code currently does not handle any map loader callbacks so it is stuck in am intermediate state.

Comment: hi @David i tried with  map = mapFragment.getMap(),still not work ,i think problem with Sdk ,can i share my source code with u

Comment: Am getting this error @ David NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "version.hybrid.api.here.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: Your device is not connected to the public internet?

Comment: hi @David, please check my source code [Github](https://github.com/ashk1246/github)

Comment: hi, I solved my issues actually my code was corrected , the problem occurred  with memory now i can render map in phone